# how to set background colur of reapeater td dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm using one repeater. In that repeater I have one column named 32. If this column gets the value = increased I want to show back color green else red

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="grdvPos" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <td >
        <%#Eval ("32")%>
       </td>
       </ItemTemplate>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemDataBound` event.

Change your aspx code as,

```
       <ItemTemplate>
          <td runat="server" ID="TD1">
            <%#Eval ("32")%>
           </td>
       </ItemTemplate>
```

and in your backend code,

```
protected void grdvPos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("TD1"); 
            if (td.InnerText.Contains("Decreased"))
                td.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Red;");
            else
              td.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Green;");
         }
}
```

Comment: giving error sayin HtmlTableCell could  not be found , are you misssing any name space

for this any namespace should i add ? @Coder of Code

Comment: Yes you need `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl` namspace. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i used"using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;" but its giving errors saying 

"A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell' is a type not a namespace"

Comment: its already added in my code 
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

Comment: solved the issue. i had not written  OnItemDataBound="grdvPos_ItemDataBound" in markup/aspx page

Comment: U r awesome  @Coder of Code . thanks for ur help . solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

aspx / design

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="grdvPos" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <td runat="server" ID="TD1" class="grdvclass backgrnd">
 <%#Eval ("32")%>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

code behind

```
protected void grdvPos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("TD1");
            if (td.InnerText.Contains("Decreased"))
                td.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Red;");
            else
                td.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Green;");
        }
    }
```

output
[image: solved]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Conditional-Values-Styles-GridView.aspx

There are multiple ways 
1) Use RowDataBound and depending upon condition change style
2) Use condition bind evaluation. In background it will use same thing.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <img src='<%# (Eval("ImageURL")==DBNull.Value ? "DefaultImage.jpg" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageURL")) %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```